# Unable to open debugger port in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, debug-mode

I have a problem that I can not set up my application in debug mode with IntelliJ IDE, but run mode is OK.

My OS is Windows 7, IDE is IntelliJ IDEA, web container is Tomcat 6. I have tried for a long time,  changed the HTTP port and the JMX port, but it did not work.

When I set up the app in debug mode with IntelliJ, it failed and the event log is:

> 16:05:35 Error running tomcat: Unable to open debugger port :
>   java.net.BindException "Address already in use: JVM_Bind".

Comment: What is normal practise and port for tomcat6 to allow debugging? You might need to enable some flags / settings...

Comment: @vikingsteve thank you! Tt is an occasional case, when I restart my computer, eveything is OK.May be some port is conflict, but I dont know which one is.

Comment: Cool :) There are also some handy tools to see which application is holding a port - worth perhaps using such a tool to identify quickly the source of the conflict. In worst case looking in windows task manager and stopping tomcat.exe, java.exe, etc might help.

Comment: Must be careful! Must not set the http port below 1024 if you are not the admin or root.Or you are always get the error " Error running tomcat: Unable to open debugger port"

Answer (score 197, accepted):

the key to the issue is in **debugger port**. I was having the same problem, I was killing every process listening on port 8081 (my http port), 1099 (JMX port), tomcat shutdown port, every java.exe, and still nothing.

The thing is this **debugger port** is different. If you run the application, it will go through the port you have Tomcat configured for, 8080, 8081 or whatever. But if you run it in Debug mode, it goes through a different port.

If you go edit your Tomcat configuration from IntelliJ, the last tab is **Startup/Connection**. Here go see the configuration for **Debug** mode, and you'll see its port. Mine was 50473. I changed it to 50472, and everything started working again.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And for those who want to solve it by closing the process holding the port, open task manager->performance->resource monitor-> network , you can find the process there.

Comment: What a pitty that there is no "autoassign unused port" option XD

Comment: Thanks a lot. -  @T.M. I was also killing all the processes.

Comment: thanks, changing the port from Startup/Connection did it for me

Comment: It's a pity this is still happening with Intellij 2019.2.3.  The change of debug port is the only way I was able to get it to work (other than rebooting my machine)

Comment: I took the advice of changing the port but I had to change it to something far away from 50473. I tried 50450, 50500, and 50400 and was still getting the same error message for all those ports. what ended up working was choosing 8085 (and I only chose that since it's close to my server's 8080 port)

Comment: If this doesn't work, make sure to check your event log for preceeding errors. In my case the JMX port was the one that was actually blocked, but the debugger port message overlayed it. Unblocking the JMX port resolved both error messages in my case, unsure why IntelliJ complained about the debugger port also.

Comment: The killing processes on the JMX port worked for me, thanks.

Comment: I tried many other ports and always the same message - address already in use... I had to delete Tomcat Configuration and create new one. After that, debugging works. Old configuration was probably somehow corrupted.

Answer (score 79):

If you're on windows you can bypass the socket issue completely by switching to shared memory debugging.

[image]

Comment: This is what helped me in the end. Before this, I needed to change ports every few hours, sometimes even that did not help... Ending the java processes also did nothing.

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion. After changing to Shared memory IntelliJ failed on another issue (my server.xml was corrupted). Fixed it and moved back to Transport. All good.

Comment: In my case it's extremely frustrating as there is NEVER any process using the port that IntelliJ says is already in use.  This option seems to have worked and hopefully I'll never again waste time using diagnostic tools to find these non-existent processes reported by IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. In my case, this started happening suddenly, without any known modification - neither an update or a new program install. Just after a Windows 7 reboot after months of using IntelliJ. Not happening on any of my other computers. And no program is using that port. I'd like to find an explanation.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 61):

For me, IntelliJ `Event Log` (right bottom corner) had below logs:

```
Error running EntitmentTooling-Debug: Cannot run program "/path-to/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory "path-to/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/bin"): error=13, Permission denied

Error running EntitmentTooling-Debug: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:58804): java.net.SocketException "Socket closed"
```

The command

```
$ chmod a+x /path-to/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/bin/catalina.sh
```

to sufficiently change privileges worked for me.

Comment: looking at `Event Log` is the key here, previous error was the root cause

Comment: This is the best answer. Works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks your answer solve my problem after several month

Answer (score 19):

I have encountered the same error while using IntelliJ. Since I have started multiple instances of IntelliJ. While starting two instance it started properly. However, when starting another one, it was giving below error.

```
unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:debug-port-number) java.net.socketexception interrupted function call accept failed
```

There are basically two places you can check your ports related to debugging in IntelliJ

1. JMX port - you can find this is
   [image]
2. In Startup/Configuration, there is debug option just click this.
   [image]

**What to Check**: If IntelliJ is throwing above error, means issue is any of the above listed ports. To verify this open event log (its available in right corner down) and check the exact message. Event log will have message like below

```
11:19 PM    Error running 'Tomcat-tp': Address localhost:1098 is already in use

11:19 PM    Error running 'Tomcat-tp': Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:51787): java.net.SocketException "Interrupted function call: accept failed"
```

**Solution-1**
Check the JMX port of current intelliJ which is not starting with the working one and  verify if JMX ports are not duplicated within IntelliJ instance or any of the software which is running in your machine is not using this port.

**Solution-2**
If JMX is not duplicated then verify your debug port, check in all IntelliJ instance and do the changes.

Surely either JMX or Debug port is having issue just use unique JMX and Debug port and it will work.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thank you. I always have multiple instances of IntelliJ running.

Comment: Thanks! Even though I recieved an error about my debugger port, the problem was in fact the duplicated JMX port.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me consistently (it happens to me from time to time, when I do things such a restart tomcat when I am running the integration tests, for example)

1) Find the process that has the port 1099 open

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep tcp | grep 1099
cp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                    LISTEN      9857/java
```

2) kill it

```
kill 9857
```

3) Start Tomcat.

Answer (score 8):

I had same issue in windows 7 and IntellijIdea 14.
I killed the java processes by going CTRL+ALT+ESc, find java and kill it.
Now Re-Run, the application again it should be fine..
You can also do it with command line or shell(linux), but I found this easier for myself

Answer (score 7):

I solved the issue by this way.

1. I tried to kill all the java.exe processes but it was useless.
2. Then I tried deleting the Tomcat server
3. I re-deployed the project and restarted the project and it worked.

See these links for more information:

Delete Tomcat
[image: Delete Tomcat]

Add a new Tomcat
[image: Add a new Tomcat]

Comment: I solved the issue by my way.
why not share it with others?

Comment: Sorry. It looked like you were asking a new question. Got confused because of the present tense("*I have the same issue*")

Comment: That's okay. Approved a pending edit on the answer which should fix all the grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact message.

The reason was that some IDE (I use Eclipse and Intellij) failed to shutdown the tomcat server.  Or maybe crashed before it could do so.

The solution was to navigate to `C:\...\apache-tomcat-xxx\bin` and run `shutdown`.

Answer (score 5):

All the other solutions unfortunately did not work.
This is what worked for me . I simply changed the debugger port to some other port number.

Intelij-> preferences->Build, execution, deployment ->Debugger-> Built in server->port(change value )

[image]

Answer (score 5):

My fix was the change debug port from 54444 to 7070

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It happens occasionally that when I restart my computer, everything is OK. Perhaps there is a port conflict.

Restart the computer works because instances of Java or Tomcat are killed during the restart. You can also consider killing the specific processes from Task Manager

This also happens if there is an issue in the context.xml file. In my case, I had accidentally changed the context value.

Comment: I tried all the mentioned solutions and nothing worked except for computer restart.

Comment: I think this is an underrated solution. It will fix most permission issues / file locking issues / zombie process issues. It's inconvenient, but the other solutions are also inconvenient, and this option lets you get up, stretch, get a drink :)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue,because my computer's DNS miss 127.0.0.1  localhost.
When I add 127.0.0.1  localhost to my host file,it become ok.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution also did the trick for me. Alternatively, provide the IP in the Intellij Debug configuration instead of the host name "localhost".

Answer (score 3):

While debug I got this issue: It worked with

1. tried changing my Tomcat http port 8082 to 8083(In debug
   configurations on IntelliJ and in Tomcat->conf->server.xml also)
2. tried changing JMX port from 1099 to 1009.
3. tried changing debug port in Startup/Connection in debug
       configurations
4. killed all java processes in TaskManager->Processes.

Answer (score 3):

There are various reasons for this.
- There might be the problem with debugger port---Please change it to resolve( answered by [T.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177058/t-m) )
- There might be some issue with intellij cache --Invalidate cache and restart will solve it ( answered by [feng smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2356912/feng-smith) )
- There might be problem with any other Port, like JMX, AJP --- Please change these port numbers as well.
**I wanted to add this as comment but not enough rep**

Answer (score 3):

My assumption that this exception usually occurs when Tomcat is improperly closed and still holding the ports.
Usually it is enough to kill any process listening to 1099 port. For Window 10:

```
netstat -aon | find "1099"


taskkill /F /PID $processId
```

Answer (score 2):

None of above methods worked in my case i.e. changing port number in run configuration, machine restart, invalidate cache in IntelliJ, killing process shown in netstat (`nestat -anob | findstr <port-number>` and then `tskill <pid>`). The only thing that finally helped was starting and shutting down tomcat manually via `startup.bat` and `shutdown.bat` (you should use correspondig `.sh` files on linux and macOS).

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked for me is to go to Task Manager on Windows, and end all the Java processes that is running by right click -> end Task.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check "Run" configuration to see which port it is using (`8081`).
2. Find all the other processes using that port `lsof -t -i :8081`
3. Kill the processes on that port. `kill PROCESS_ID`
4. Run Tomcat in Debug mode.

In my case, I wasted so much time on changing **debugger port** but it **was not** the issue. Since tomcat was not able to run on the port I chose in **Run** configuration, I was not able to debug my service.

Answer (score 2):

In **Server** tab of Tomcat configuration in IntelliJ, change **JMX port** to another number.

Comment: This worked for me and the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 2):

Change debug port of your server configured in the Intelli J.

It will be fixed.[image]

Comment: Even after change also its not working .. I have open multiple instance and few of them it working not for all.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had another project open in IntelliJ, and had Tomcat running in debug mode in that project.
Stopping that instance of Tomcat resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I came in this scenario and as the above answers I tried to change the port like
Edit Configuration -> Startup/Connection -> debug -> change the Port
but it didn't solve my problem cause I was running my application in debug mode so once try to run the application as normal without debug.
it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem in server.xml for Tomcat/conf folder where I had extra comment tags under another comment tag. So I think, since there was some problem in server.xml, it was not able to start Tomcat. And moreover it copies the tomcat folder from your installation directory to C:\Users\username.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_service

Comment: Your answer does not seem to help with the OP question. What should he do?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have application running on the same port number. One way to do this by killing the process forcefully. Open command prompt as an admin. Run command 'taskkill /IM "java.exe" /F'. This worked for me in Windows. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get the same error message if the standalone.xml in your standalone/configuration folder cannot be found. At least I have the same error when using a WildFly 14.0.1:

[image: Error running WildFly 14.01.1: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:1233): java.net.SocketException "socket closed"]

Answer (score 0):

Just **restart the Android studio** before try these all. I face same right now and i fix it by this way.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes here with the similar message:

```
Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:50470):
    java.net.SocketException "Interrupted function call: accept failed"
```

This may be caused by something completely independent, i.e. it's not a port configuration. If you're running Tomcat, for instance, it may be that you have an invalid `web.xml`. Check your Event Log for any previous errors:

```
Cannot load C:\...\conf\web.xml: ParseError at [row,col]:[480,29]
            Message: The element type "param-value" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</param-value>".
```

[image: IntellIj error log screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is **sometimes** just because of a misconfiguration.

Please, check if you have, for example, an SSL port number defined at your run configuration. If so, and if you don't have a right configuration for it at tomcat's server.xml, then it won't be possible to start your debug session correctly, and you will unfortunately have the same error. I think this can be shown as a different error. So, this is in my opinion an idea issue also..

The solution is, removing the SSL port number value from the run configuration of the IDE.

#intellij-idea
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intellij-idea

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me, when I was running wildfly on intellij, and I switched the branch. I stopped wildfly, built the jar using maven, tried to re run Wildfly and got the error.

I tried changing port as mentioned in the accepted answer, but didn't work. I tried to find the process running on port, but **netstat** command didn't find it.

I tried restarting the OS, it also didn't help.

Then I checked the configuration folder of my Wildfly set up, that's when I realised

> **standalone.xml** got replaced by **standalone.xml.tmp**

renaming it to standalone.xml helped me to resolve the error.

Answer (score -1):

Running IntelliJ as Administrator in Windows did the magic for me:
[image: Run as administrator]

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple solution for the same.

1. Either we may close the IDE (e.g. IntellJ)
2. Find t
   IND00123:bin devbratanand$ lsof -i:30303
   COMMAND PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   idea    437 devbratanand   56u  IPv4 0xb2720e580a7d6483      0t0  TCP 10.17.130.41:55222->vmqp-cms-pan-app1.emea.akqa.local:30303 (ESTABLISHED)
   IND00123:bin devbratanand$ kill -9 437