# ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

When I am trying to use `sbt shell` in intelliJ it appears the following error message:

[image]

Do I miss any settings?

**Update**

```
netstat -planet
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41351           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       353424     573/java            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       355674     573/java            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33295           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       354289     573/java            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        16065      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          34359      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       354471     573/java            
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:42510         151.101.193.69:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       305742     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:44344         104.66.167.140:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       345081     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:37646         198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       353330     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:41480         104.16.29.34:443        ESTABLISHED 1000       349198     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp      564      0 10.0.2.15:43148         172.217.168.42:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       377410     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:59768         54.246.222.93:443       ESTABLISHED 1000       368480     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:40474         216.58.215.226:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       327204     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:37728         198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       376381     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:40470         216.58.215.226:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       327196     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:56458         34.193.164.107:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       352517     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:52954         91.228.74.181:443       ESTABLISHED 1000       377413     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:52956         91.228.74.181:443       ESTABLISHED 1000       377416     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:39020         172.217.168.66:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       324280     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:39324         216.58.215.230:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       375801     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:38640         172.217.168.38:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       352610     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:50876         172.217.168.46:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       343823     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:36630         198.252.206.25:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       327486     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:40544         216.58.215.227:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       318302     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:47506         151.101.194.49:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       353343     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp      311      0 10.0.2.15:38920         13.32.166.42:443        ESTABLISHED 1000       377418     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:54224         192.30.253.125:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       317858     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:49846         172.217.168.46:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       327213     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:56456         34.193.164.107:443      ESTABLISHED 1000       351738     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp       32      0 10.0.2.15:42114         52.207.55.4:443         CLOSE_WAIT  1000       374681     5102/chromium-brows 
tcp6       0      0 :::43209                :::*                    LISTEN      1000       355214     772/java            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          34358      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:30107         :::*                    LISTEN      1000       355213     772/java            
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:43906         127.0.0.1:33295         TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:43904         127.0.0.1:33295         TIME_WAIT   0          0          -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:43922         127.0.0.1:33295         TIME_WAIT   0          0          -
```

**Update 2**

What do I have to set:

[image]

Comment: Before you start the shell make sure nothing is running on port `45451`. And you test via telnet `localhost 41351` if connects to port on a localhost. If you have global sbt shell configured, disable it as it can cause such issue.

Comment: Yes I uninstalled global `sbt` and tried to run it, but got the same error. When I start intellj, then `sbt shell` starts automatically, how to prevent the start?

Comment: Are you sure about this? Sbt shell should not start on IDE start. It starts when you open SBT shell tool window.

Comment: Yes, you are right!!What should I do, that the error does not appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This used to (2015) suggest a port already in used (as in [ensime/ensime-server issue 921](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/issues/921))
You have the [same error with JBoss](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/166451?_sscc=t) for instance

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Cannot assign requested address
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized
```

Make sure there isn't already an sbt shell running elsewhere ([`netstat -planet`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41820474/6309)).

Comment: @zero_coding There seems to be another sbt shell instance, on port 41351. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3437

Comment: I can not recognize, there is another `sbt shell` instance. I restarted intellj and the error still appears.

Comment: @zero_coding I suppose the error would persist even after a reboot? (just for testing)

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is, that I installed sbt globally. I will try to delete it first.

Comment: Now, I also restart my computer and still does not work.

Comment: @zero_coding Then check the settings from Intellij IDEA / scala: it is possible it *already* starts an sbt shell.

Answer (score 0):

For macos users, might be due to lack of the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

in /etc/hosts.

I fixed the same issue by adding that line